# I use a virtual enviornment, PyCharm doesn't recognize "flask_login" is a python package, even though it recognizes other packages

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, virtual-environment

I want to import a few tools from flask_login, I already downloaded it in cmd (I navigated to where my directory is located, activated my virtual enviorment and wrote "pip install Flask-Login" I later found it there with 'pip list'), but there's an error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'.
When I put my cursor over flask_login there's this note "Unresolved reference 'flask_login'".

I work with PyCharm, when there's a package I want to import, but I haven't downloaded yet, PyCharm shows me the option to download it (in the red lightbulb button). However, for this package it doesn't.

When I use the normal interpeter, it works just fine (I've donwloaded flask_login there too).

I followed ChatGPT instructions - I cleared Pycharm's cache/restarted it and re-indexed my project (According to Pycharm it's the same steps - 'File' > 'Invalidate Cache' > 'Invalidate and Restart'), it didn't help.

I would be really happy if someone could help me, I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know why is that, but the problem was solved after downloading flask_login again, but now in the PyCharm terminal and not in the cmd as I did before.